# MariaDb silent install of a msi with innosetup doesn't work

Tags: mysql, windows-installer

I try to install MariaDB silently with inno setup, but it doesn't install.

```
 [Files] 
    Source: "mariadb-10.1.9-win32.msi"; DestDir: "{tmp}"
 [Run]   
    Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\mariadb-10.1.9-win32.msi SERVICENAME=MySQL DATADIR=C:\mydata\DB PORT=3306 UTF8=1"" /qn"
```

The right folder is created but only the uninstall files are put into it.

If I run this in cmd started as administrator it works and mariaDB is ready for use

```
msiexec.exe /i E:\Installatie\mariadb-10.1.9-win32.msi SERVICENAME=MySQL DATADIR=C:\mydata\DB  PORT=3306 /qn
```

ps I ommited the password

I modified the files Source:

```
[Files] 
"mariadb-10.1.9-win32.msi";  DestName: "mariadb-10.1.9-win32.msi"; DestDir: "c:\temp"
```

and I removed the parameters then I get the mariaDB installer. So why doesn't it work with the parameters.
I get exitcode 1619

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking why an install doesn't work. There is no indication that this is anything to do with programming or development or dev tools.

Comment: @PhilDW: Software installation tools are among the *tools used by developers*, and therefore questions about installers are on topic here.

Comment: I modified the files Source: "mariadb-10.1.9-win32.msi";  DestName: "mariadb-10.1.9-win32.msi"; DestDir: "c:\temp"

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. In the run section put:

```
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i {app}\mariadb-5.2.9-win32.msi PORT=3306 PASSWORD=xxxxxx SERVICENAME=MySQL ADDLOCAL=ALL REMOVE=DEVEL,HeidiSQL INSTALLDIR=""C:\mariadb"" /L*v log.txt /qb"; WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: waituntilterminated skipifdoesntexist
```

The version I tried is 5 but it should work properly with 10 too.
My problem was with double quotation marks after /i and once the ones were removed, the installation was performed perfectly and silently (/ qb) and create a log.txt file for mariadb installation.

Answer (score 0):

Likely explanation: When you run it as admin it runs elevated and succeeds. When you run it silently it cannot ask for elevation and fails because it requires elevated privilege, so try it by running your InnoSetup as admin.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows 10 and it didn't work because of the {tmp}. When I use a path like c:\temp instead of {tmp} it works